# In-browser player for SHOUTcast .pls file

Tags: plugins

gang.

I run [Galactic Journey](https://galacticjourney.org), which is a WordPress site, and one of the things we do is run a SHOUTcast radio station at http://68.8.114.145:8005/ -- if you click Listen, you get a .pls file, which can be downloaded and opened in VLC or Winamp.

I'd like to have it so the media player is embedded in the site so it's a one-button thing. I tried https://webdev-il.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-stream-pls-file-in-web-page.html but it didn't work.

Any ideas for a quick fix? A plugin? Thanks much!